# Show HTML table header only on page break, set display none for 1st occurence

Tags: html, css

I have a table something like this:-

```
<table>
<thead><tr><td>Heading1</td><td>Heading2</td></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The number of rows in tbody might be so much that when printing table, it might have a page break.
What I need to do is I need to display table header only on page break, i.e. it should NOT be printed on the very first page, but on the pages which load due to a page break.

I know I can repeat table header on all pages in IE, using the css:

```
table thead {display: table-header-group;}
```

But how can I achieve this scenario?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?